# counting the forecasts of 20 chess games

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have a Question...

> The results of 20 chess games (win, lose, draw) have to be predicted. How many different forecasts can contain exactly **15 correct results?**

I don't really understand this question...Please tell me how to solve this question.

Thanks!!

Comment: The question needs interpretation. Under my favoured one (probably not the intended one!) the answer is $3^{20}$. But they probably want one to say $\binom{20}{15}2^5$.

Comment: 3 raised to 20 is the total number of forecasts

Comment: Yes, and **any** forecast could contain exactly $15$ items that turn out to be correct. Now if the games have already been played, we get my second answer.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of guessing correctly a single game is $\frac13$.

The probability of guessing correctly exactly $15$ out $20$ games is therefore:

$$\binom{20}{15}\cdot\left(\frac13\right)^{15}\cdot\left(1-\frac13\right)^{20-15}$$

Comment: can you tell me what they mean by 15 correct forecasts

Comment: @ghaprameya: What part of "15 correct forecasts" don't you understand?????